# Minimum of sum using AM-GM

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $x > y > 0$, find the minimum of
$x + \frac{8}{(y)(x-y)}$.

I have just introduced myself to inequalities (mainly AM-GM) and am trying to use the fact that the minimum of a sum is when both terms are equal, but only when their product is fixed. However I am unable to prove that the product of these two are constant.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=y+a$.

Hence, by AM-GM
$$x+\frac{8}{y(x-y)}=a+y+\frac{8}{ay}\geq a+\frac{4\sqrt2}{\sqrt{a}}=$$
$$=a+\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt{a}}\geq3\sqrt[3]{a\left(\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^2}=6.$$
The equality occurs for $a=2$, $x=4$ and $y=2$, which says that $6$ is a minimal value.

Comment: Thank you! I never would have thought of that though. Do you have any advice for how to approach these sort of inequalities and how to reduce them to AM-GM?

Comment: @Champ I knew that $x+\frac{1}{x}\geq2$ for $x>0$ and I made something similar.

Comment: You could have gone: $a+y+\frac{8}{ay}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{a\cdot y\cdot \frac{8}{ay}}=3\cdot 2=6.$

Comment: @farruhota Yes of course!